# No power situation - 1990 Mercury Couger

Tags: engine, electrical, starting

The engine won't turn over and there is no radio or power windows.

What is the connection with these three things all at once?

I replaced the coil and starter.  Checked fuses, relays, etc.  It acts like it wants to start.  Motor fires but won't turn over.

Comment: Have you checked the battery?

Comment: What do you mean by *Motor fires but won't turn over*? Usually, it's the other way around, in that it will crank but won't fire. The term "fire" usually indicating that it kicks or has some life to it (ie: the spark plugs are firing). Can you describe this a little better?

Answer (score 1):

The engine not turning over is related to your starter circuit or your starter relay.  If you have a good battery and your relay is functioning, you will here a clicking sound as you turn the ignition key to try and start the car.

The power windows and radio have their own circuits, typically dedicated to the use.  Radio, circuit, window circuit, lights, etc..

If your battery is in good shape, you may have a main fuse issue for the overall vehicle.  Checking fuses with a multi-meter to ensure they are in working order rather than visual inspection is recommended.  I've seen fuses that appeared fine but were not when tested for continuity.

Starting at the batter to ensure it's in good working order is recommended.  All of these symptoms can be attributed to a bad battery.